# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'company_name' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ambiguous

I am trying to have an AND in my statement but everytime I run the code I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'company_name' in where clause is ambiguous

```sql
select tblcomplaints.*,user.name as name,category.categoryName as
    catname from tblcomplaints join user on user.id=tblcomplaints.userId join category on 
    category.id=tblcomplaints.category where tblcomplaints.complaintNumber=".$cid." AND company_name=$companyname`
```

Comment: Edit your post to add the **structure** of your **tables** to better understand your error

Answer (score 4):

According to the error, two or more of the tables in the query have a `company_name` column. You can fix the error by full qualifying the column with a table name. E.g., if it's in the `user` table:

```sql
select tblcomplaints.*, user.name as name, category.categoryName as catname
from   tblcomplaints 
join   user on user.id = tblcomplaints.userId
join   category on category.id = tblcomplaints.category
where  tblcomplaints.complaintNumber = ".$cid." AND 
       user.company_name = $companyname
-- Here^
```

**Side note:**
Concatenating strings into SQL statements like this may make your application vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. I strongly recommend you look into [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) as a safer approach.

Comment: yes table content has and user have both collumn company_name im now getting another error    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Comment: That error goes on to say WHICH COLUMN is unknown! So which column is it

Comment: silly me i had not declared that column in the user table .. thank you so much for your time